# view composers using wildcard * to load a variable inside all the views laravel 5

Tags: laravel, performance

How will it affect the performance? if I loaded a variable inside all the views using view composers even if I'm not using this variable inside all the views.
is it recommended to do that? please provide your answer with an article.
using this service provider.

```
 View::composer(
        [
            '*',
        ],
        function ($view) {
            $masterLayout = ;//get variable from database
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, obviously there will be a negative impact on the performance of the site if you're querying for data that is possibly not used, but, you could always use caching to alleviate the effect:

```
View::composer(['*'], function ($view) {
    $masterLayout = Cache::rememberForever('master_layout', function() {
        return DB::table('layouts')->where('name', 'master')->first();
    });
});
```

Comment: So it's okay to load this variable event if we are using the cache?

Comment: BTW, the pecentage of using the variable inside the files around 5%.

Comment: Yeah the variable loading is trivial compared to making repetitive queries every request.

Comment: Just for upcoming files, we don't need to touch this one again.